# Laravel not executing scheduled command

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-artisan

I'm using laravel telescope. I used the following code to schedule the prune command in kernel.php (it has 48 hours but I already tried with less hours):

```
$schedule->command('telescope:prune --hours=48')->daily();
```

I tested it in my local environment and it prunes the data correctly. But once in my production server it doesn't seem to be working.

Telescope is runing there and capturing data. I thought it could be a telescope command issue, but I ran

```
php artisan telescope:prune
```

and it works, it says "25404 entries pruned", I also verified this in the DB. Also, my cron task is runing every minute, and I have some scheduled calls like this:

```
$schedule->call('*some irrelevant stuff*')->cron('0 */3 * * *');
$schedule->call('*some irrelevant stuff*')->dailyAt('00:00');
```

And they are working as expected. I also tried calling the scheduller manually inside a function:

```
Artisan::call('schedule:run');
```

and the schedule calls work, but "$schedule->command" does not.

So, I'm guessing that the problem is that somehow "$schedule->command" is not working. Do you have any idea or suggestion to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should set Laravel Task Scheduler to your's servers crontab file, adding the following entry:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Would u please specify what stars stand for?

Comment: Sure. The stars represent the time wich the command should be executed: * minute (0 - 59) * hour (0 - 23) * day of month (1 - 31) * month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ... * day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat. Here you can find a complete guide about cron use: 
https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux